# ValueEventListener won't get executed after setting adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a viewPager and in each viewPager i have a ListView.\

When i run my app, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown in CourseListAdapter because `ValueEventListener` is not executed...

But when i remove `listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` my listview won't be populated but i see `D/CourseListAdapter: Getting information` in my logger..

My Fragment who sets the ListView:

```
public class DayFragment
        extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "DayFragment";

    private CourseListAdapter mAdapter;

    private int day = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course_list, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        // Yay a day is given
        if (bundle != null) {
            day = bundle.getInt("day");
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        mAdapter = new CourseListAdapter(getActivity(), day);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        Log.i(TAG, "Removing the listener");

        // Clean up
        mAdapter.removeListener();
    }
}
```

My ListView adapter:

```
public class CourseListAdapter
        extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "CourseListAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Day> mDays = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mDay = 0;
    private ValueEventListener mListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mReference;

    public CourseListAdapter(final Activity context, int day) {
        mContext = context;
        mDay = day;

        // Setup Firebase
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = mDatabase.getReference();

        mListener = mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Getting information");

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Day day = postSnapshot.getValue(Day.class);

                    for (DataSnapshot course : postSnapshot.child("courses").getChildren()) {
                        day.addCourse(course.getValue(Course.class));
                    }

                    mDays.add(day);
                }

                // Tell some data changed
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Listen was cancelled, no more updates will occur");
            }
        });
    }

    public void removeListener() {
        mReference.removeEventListener(mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Day day = mDays.get(mDay);

        return day.getCourses().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Day day = mDays.get(mDay);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.course_items, parent, false);

            viewHolder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.course);
            viewHolder.classRoom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.class_room);
            viewHolder.begin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.begin);
            viewHolder.end = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end);
            viewHolder.teacher = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teacher);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.course.setText(day.getCourses().get(position).name);
        viewHolder.classRoom.setText(day.getCourses().get(position).classRoom);
        viewHolder.begin.setText(day.getCourses().get(position).from);
        viewHolder.end.setText(day.getCourses().get(position).to);
        viewHolder.teacher.setText(day.getCourses().get(position).teacher);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView course;
        TextView classRoom;
        TextView begin;
        TextView end;
        TextView teacher;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing data from Firebase is an asynchronous operation which means it doesn't happen right away so you first need to get all the data you need from firebase, and only when you finish collecting all the data, set the listview adapter. I mean you need to set the adapter only when onDataChange is finished, you can make a public static method to set the adapter and call it from the onDataChange after the for loops.

Comment: My database is public. If i remove the ```listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);``` part it works...

Comment: Can you publish the error log? i mean, where IndexOutOfBoundsException happened?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/VjpZgCdh The exception is called on ```Day day = mDays.get(mDay);``` in the ```getCount``` method. Because the "ValueEventListener" wont get called the array is empty!

Comment: I edited my answer. I think this is the reason for your error.